# Authentification with Belgian Card (BEID)

Tags: ssl, eid

I am currently working on setting up an authentication via the Belgian identity card on a web page.

I understood that the applet was abandoned.

So I do not know what to turn to, there is the extension firefox but I can not find any doc. I also understand that tax-on-web used a technic via SSL but I did not understand or find more info.

Would you have any tips to give me?

thank you

Comment: "Any leads?" is almost by definition too broad.

Comment: google trad :) i mean tips